# Uniqueness of spanning trees made using search algorithms?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, algorithms, trees, searching

For undirected graphs, the corresponding spanning trees can be obtained using various search algorithms like **Depth-first search algorithm** , **Bredth-first algorithm**, etc.

I am not sure whether the spanning trees generated using these algorithms are unique or not. I mean is it possible that through a particular algorithm, we can get two different spanning tress for the same graph?

Comment: why does it matter?

Comment: @paulpaul1076 - Sorry, I didn't get you.